# Запретить перенос строки

Tags: html, css

При нажатии на enter текст в h1 переносится, необходимо эту возможность устранить.

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto ">
            <h1 class="name" id="name" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Заголовок" style="font-size: 36px; white-space:nowrap;" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 180)"></h1>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Свойство white-space:nowrap - не работает :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. js поможет Вам если не надо менять html структуру

```js
document.querySelector('#name').addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.code == 'KeyV' && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) || e.code == 'Enter' || e.code == 'NumpadEnter') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})


document.querySelector('#name').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
   if (e.code == 'KeyV' && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) || e.code == 'Enter' || e.code == 'NumpadEnter') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})

document.querySelector('#name').addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto ">
        <h1 class="name" id="name" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Заголовок" style="font-size: 36px; white-space:nowrap;" onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 180)">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quod, modi! Suscipit placeat vitae, impedit harum voluptas temporibus earum amet.
        </h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Wild Developer если ответ удовлетворил Вашим требованиям обычно он отмечается галочкой ...

Comment: А внезапно `Ctrl + V` ? P.S. `return`  - лишнее

Comment: P.P.S. На кнопке Enter в цифровом блоке может и не сработать. Надо добавить в проверку "`NumpadEnter`"

Comment: @Deonis исправил посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Вопрос, связанный с копипастом, нужно как-то решать в другом русле. Запрещать не нужно, а вот удалять переносы строк в таком случае - может быть решением. К тому же, не забывайте, что вставить данные можно не только комбинацией клавиш, но и из контекстного меню: паравй клик > Вставить

Comment: @Deonis как можно сделать с переносом строк ? а такое решение контекстного меню: паравй клик > Вставить  ?

Comment: @Deonis ну вот помотросил и бросил ...

Comment: Послушайте, я не собирался вас критиковать и в принципе задерживаться в этой теме, а только указал на некоторые недочеты, которые сразу бросились в глаза. )) Лично для меня эта тема не имеет какого-то смысла по двум причинам: 1. Если данные после редактирования нигде сохраняться не будут, то зачем что-то запрещать пользователю вводить у себя в клиенте? 2. Если данные будут сохраняться, то пусть он вводит хоть переносы строк, хоть прабабушку с прадедушкой, а всё не нужное я удалю на сервере. Ну и для конкретной задачи, вполне подойдёт вариант @soledar10, чтобы просто притормозить юзера.

Comment: @Deonis Извините если что ... я после Вашего комментария решил что есть какой-то коварный, глубинный, скрытный и. т. д. способ решения чем у меня :)) А Вы такой "злодей" со мной не делитесь :))

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант

```css
#name {
  font-size: 36px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#name br {
  display: none;
}

#name * {
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="name" id="name" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Заголовок">
  This should work.
</h1>
```